# Identify when Table Schemas were last Modified

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to identify all tables that have had indices added/altered since January 15. Is this possible?

I've run:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS where UPDATE_TIME >= '2019-01-15'
```

but this is returning tables that had their content updated, not structure.

Maybe there's a different `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table I should use? I'm running mysql 5.6 if that makes a difference. I'm using `myisam` and `innodb` tables (majority are `innodb`).

Comment: MySQL do not collet this data. Only general log (if enabled) may help.

Comment: @Akina It looks like the `general_log` would become quite large, it logs all queries?

Comment: Of course. Moreover, it is both disk and resource-exepensive. But AFAIR there is no another method to log DDL in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

When InnoDB add an index it adds a record to `I_S.INNODB_SYS_INDEXES`. `INDEX_ID` of a new index will be highest. Analyzing existing records you can get an idea in what order indexes where created, but that's it. `INNODB_SYS_INDEXES` doesn't contain any time fields.

On other hand, any DML will be logged to a binlog. If it's enabled and it hasn't been rotated yet you will see the `ALTER TABLE` with a timestamp.

Comment: What about `myisam` tables, any solution for those? The binlog on my system is 70 GBs so grepping that is not readable.

Comment: Why is 70G not readable?

Comment: Use `mysqlbinlog` to read the binlog; grep its output.